# Minecraft PlotSquared plugin help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am staff on a server and I am trying to set up a creative world. I have successfully made a world full of only creative plots. But the problem is that you can break any block on any plot claimed or not claimed. If it helps you to figure out my problem at all, we are using the plugins MutliVerse and PlotSquared.

Comment: Check your permissions.

Comment: How do I check my permissions?

Comment: most plugins have a permission system. if you don't know how to use permissions, you shouldn't be doing something like this. Heres a link: https://github.com/IntellectualSites/PlotSquared/wiki/Commands-and-Permissions

Comment: Have you tested if other players that don't have OP for example can still break those blocks?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be you do not have a permissions plugin.

Plugins like multiverse and plotsquared are made to work with a permissions handler. The way it sounds, every player in the specified world does not have permissions restricting them from building anywhere and the plotsquared plugin alone does not handle what players have access to in terms of building without a permissions plugin.

The most common plugin for this is here:
http://www.curse.com/bukkit-plugins/minecraft/permissionsex

Comment: Also if your op, your allowed to break anywhere. I believe with that plugin if your a non-op your only allowed to break stuff in your own plots

Answer (score 0):

If your staff they may of given you * and you have all the permission.  Your best bet is to have an alt with no rank, so you are able to test if it works and not have the overrides the plugin offers to build anywhere that you get from the *

Answer (score -4):

If You do `/help` it deciphers whether you're opped or not. Depends on how many pages you own under `/help`.

Comment: You have some spelling mistakes which make this answer hard to understand. Can you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: -1 **You're wrong!** | By default, any player can use the `/help` command, regardless of being op'd or not. The only way that `/help` *can't* be used is if a `deny` permission was placed in.

Comment: -1... If I could. STAFF makes the /help command lol